# extract string from in R using regex

Tags: r, regex

I have this vector:

```
jvm<-c("test - PROD_DB_APP_185b@SERVER01" ,"uat - PROD_DB_APP_SYS[1]@SERVER2")
```

I need to extract text until "[" or if there is no "[", then until the "@" character.

result should be

```
PROD_DB_APP_185b
PROD_DB_APP_SYS
```

I've tried something like this:

```
str_match(jvm, ".*\\-([^\\.]*)([.*)|(@.*)")
```

not working, any ides?

Comment: OR   sub("(\\\[.*)?@.*", "", jvm)

Comment: @Sotos, sorry, your answer was right, one quick modification, between "-" and "[" or "@"

Comment: Your requirements do not match the expected result.

Comment: `I have this vector` - If this were a string you could match something, using `(?<=-[ ])[^\[@]+(?=[\[@])`

Comment: Try [`sub("^.*?\\s+-\\s+([^@[]+).*", "\\1", jvm)`](http://ideone.com/kMXA2o)

Comment: Or `str_extract(jvm, "(?<=- )[^@\\[]+")`

Answer (score 1):

A `sub`  solution with  base R:

```
jvm<-c("test - PROD_DB_APP_185b@SERVER01" ,"uat - PROD_DB_APP_SYS[1]@SERVER2")
sub("^.*?\\s+-\\s+([^@[]+).*", "\\1", jvm)
```

See the [online R demo](http://ideone.com/uOoGoy)

**Details**:

- `^` - start of string
- `.*?` - any 0+ chars as few as possible
- `\\s+-\\s+` - a hyphen enclosed with 1 or more whitespaces
- `([^@[]+)`  - capturing group 1 matching any 1 or more chars other than `@` 
  and `[`
- `.*` - any 0+ chars, up to the end of string.

Or a *stringr* solution with `str_extract`:

```
str_extract(jvm, "(?<=-\\s)[^@\\[]+")
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/T5aiNu/1)

**Details**:

- `(?<=-\\s)`  - a positive lookbehind that matches an empty string that is preceded with a `-` and a whitespace immediately to the left of the current location
- `[^@\\[]+` - 1 or more chars other than `@` and `[`.